# FBSDKLoginManager not handling logInWithPublishPermissions: correctly

Tags: ios, facebook-login, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm implementing v4.1 of the SDK for iOS and when I try to call for publishPermissions:, I get no callback.

For some reason everything works perfectly when I run logInWithReadPermissions:, but when I run logInWithPublishPermissions: it never hits my response handler. Nothing happens.

To test things out, I reset my loginManager before running logInWithPublishPermissions:, and to my surprise it worked then (aka NSLog(@"RESULT") is called).

Am I missing something about how the loginManager works? Shouldn't I be able to use it without resetting it?

```
// FacebookController.m

@implementation FacebookController

FBSDKLoginManager *loginManager;
static FacebookController *_shared = nil;

- (id)init { 
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        userData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

        loginManager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

+ (id)getInstance { 
    if (!_shared) {
        _shared = [[self alloc] init];
    }
    return _shared;
}

- (bool)hasPublishPermissions {
    FBSDKAccessToken *accessToken = [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken];

    if(accessToken != NULL){
        NSSet *permissions = [accessToken permissions];
        if([permissions containsObject:@"publish_actions"]){
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}

- (void)requestPublishPermissionsWithDelegate:(id)aDelegate {
    if(![self hasPublishPermissions]){
        // FOR SOME REASON IT WORKS IF I RESET LOGIN MANAGER AS FOLLOWS
        // loginManager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init]; 

        [loginManager logInWithPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"RESULT: %@", result);
        }];
    }
}

- (void)connectToFacebookWithDelegate:(id)aDelegate {        
    FBSDKAccessToken *accessToken = [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken];

    if(accessToken != nil){
        [aDelegate performSelector:@selector(facebookSignedIn)];
    } else {
        [loginManager logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                // Process error
                NSLog(@"ERROR");
            } else if (result.isCancelled) {
                // Handle cancellations
                NSLog(@"CANCELLED");
            } else {
                NSLog(@"SUCCESS");
                [aDelegate performSelector:@selector(facebookSignedIn)];
            }
        }];
    }
}
@end
```

Edit #1:
Including videos of it working and not working for the given scenarios:

Not working (loginManager reinitialization commented out):
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14277258/not-working.mov

Working (loginManager reinitialized):
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14277258/working.mov

Comment: Hi, should we send it for review for add publish actions from status&review?

Comment: still having this problem until today

Answer (score 1):

Your video stack trace indicates you're calling the request for publish permissions inside the handler for your initial login. This should be avoided:

1. You're causing another login after the user has already granted you some permissions - it's not very good for the user to have to see another login dialog immediately after completing one.
2. You're asking for publish permissions when you don't need it - this may violate Facebook developer policies and again is not the best user experience. Instead you should asking for publish only when you need it (i.e., at the time of sharing).

If you really insist, you can dispatch your second login call asynchronously so that the first request finishes entirely but I wouldn't recommend it. We can probably update the SDK to detect this and log though so it's not as confusing.

Comment: does it even trigger the app switch to perform the login (i.e., do you see the login dialog)? I'm not able to reproduce the symptom so more information would be helpful - you can also submit a report to developers.facebook.com/bugs if you want to include confidential code.

Comment: Added an edit with a couple links to videos showing the code & simulator for both situations.

Comment: Chris, thanks for getting back to me. In our app, a user can login with facebook from the get-go or they can login with a username/password and connect facebook later. A common scenario for someone who registered with a username/password is to be in the middle of submitting a photo and decide they want to share to FB as well. In this case, I'm forced to show a double dialog - once for general read permissions, once for publish permissions. I suppose I can do the second call async so that it doesn't occur within the first handler, but that feels a bit clunky to me.

Comment: Do you find any solutions? I'm getting the same problem when I'm requesting publish permissions.

Comment: me too I have this same problem for devices that are over iPhone 6